# Windows registry -- Malware

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, malware, malware-removal

I wanted to analyse some malware but I'm stuck with the registry of windows,
and was wondering if some of you could help me to understand some of it.

It actually modified some values in the registry such as:

```
> HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\ServiceCurrent\: 0x0000000A
> HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\ServiceCurrent\: 0x0000000C
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceCurrent\: 0x0000000A
> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceCurrent\: 0x0000000C
```

Which I don't understand at all, and this:

```
> HKU\S-1-5-21-117609710-1682526488-1708537768-500\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Discardable\PostSetup\ShellNew\Wave Sound: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 57 00 61 00 76 00 65 00 20 00 53 00 6F 00 75 00 6E 00 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2E 00 77 00 61 00 76 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 73 00 6F 00 75 00 6E 00 64 00 72 00 65 00 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

If someone could help me with those values, that would be great!

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Comment: Why are you messing around with *malware*? ...Do you like it when your computer blows up?

Comment: I can tell you S-1-5-21-117609710-1682526488-1708537768-500 is a SID.

Comment: I just want to understand :) it's not messing with malwares I have the malware on my computer ... that's why i want to learn

Answer (score 1):

That malware is exploiting the [**Service Control Manager - Named Pipe Vulnerability**](http://www.securityfocus.com/advisories/2472).

The last entry is for the Wave Sound in the **New Menu** in **Explorer**, the malware has most likely modified that entry for the current user so that it **might break** the New Menu, although it's discardable...

Comment: You get +1 for knowing what OP was talking about.

Comment: Do you know what the values means ? or how I can know the signification of those values ?

Comment: @xabe: `ServiceCurrent` is explained in that article, it's used to exploid [Named Pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#Named_pipes_in_Windows) as you can change their name by changing `ServiceCurrent`. The other value you mention is as I said in my answer. But well, wouldn't you rather want to restore these to the default and track where the malware itself is?

Comment: I actually would like to restore the values of those, but i don't know how I could do it because i have no save of the previous state.

Comment: These keys `ServiceCurrent` and `Wave Sound` don't exist here.

Comment: Actually it modified a lot of other keys, i could identify them, but i was wondering if just stoping the malware and deleting the new keys would be enough

Comment: Maybe, if you are unsure, you'll be best off with reinstalling. Anyhow, try Google for those keys and you might find what caused this...